# Display all unique rows in PHP Loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop in PHP:

```
$Directli = new Directli();
$output = $Directli->build_query('getPayments');
foreach($output as $row) {

}
```

i want to echo information inside the loop but only each unique row based on `$row->ID`

Comment: sorry, what do you need?

Comment: to show each row that the loop returns but only the unique rows (where ID is unique)

Comment: You might want to use the `array_unique` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Remove duplicate with array_unique. (Sorry @naota was writting when you already posted the comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique). You may call it before the loop, to get array with the unique items. If you can't use it, than you have to build a hash inside the loop, to check if the item was already processed or not:

```
$map = array();
foreach($output as $row) {
 if (!isset($map[$row->ID])) {
    $map[$row->ID] = true;
    echo $row->ID;
 }
}
```

Comment: After his edit I guess he is in the second case. He should build a separated with all the processed id.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could create a container which will hold the ids, then check inside the loop if its not yet in there, push it inside.

```
$ids = array();
foreach($output as $row) {
    if(!in_array($row->ID, $ids)) {
        $ids[] = $row->ID;
        // other process below that you need to do
        echo $row->ID;
    }
}
```

If this resultant array came from a `SELECT` statement, consider using a `DISTINCT` clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have formatted your question with your code, example and theory..

```
<?php 
.. // your connections etc .. //
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `id`='$id'"); // $id you are giving here $row->ID
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$output = array($res);
foreach($output as $row => $result)
{
echo $result;

}
?>
```

**you can also use while**

```
 <?php 
    .. // your connections etc .. //
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `something` WHERE `id`='$id'"); // $id you are giving here $row->ID
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql));
    {
    echo $result;

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**use array_unique:**

$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
where $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");  //for example
```